# remove duplicates int number in a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to remove the same integer numbers in a vector. My aim is to have only one copy them. Well I wrote a simple code, but it doesn't work properly. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()

{   

int a = 10, b = 10 , c = 8, d = 8, e = 10 , f = 6;
vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(a);
vec.push_back(b);
vec.push_back(c);
vec.push_back(d);
vec.push_back(e);
vec.push_back(f);


for (int i=vec.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    for(int j=vec.size()-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        if(vec[j] == vec[i-1])
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + j);
    }
}   

for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
{
    cout<< "vec: "<< vec[i]<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want duplicate, why not use `std::set` instead?

Comment: @Nawaz: perhaps he needs contiguous storage -- or the faster iteration performance. Or perhaps the container is not supposed to *never* have duplicates, but just remove them at specific times. There are plenty of reasons to not blindly replace it with `std::set`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates it's easier if you sort the array first. The code below uses two different methods for removing the duplicates: one using the built-in C++ algorithms and the other using a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 10 , c = 8, d = 8, e = 10 , f = 6;
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(a);
    vec.push_back(b);
    vec.push_back(c);
    vec.push_back(d);
    vec.push_back(e);
    vec.push_back(f);

    // Sort the vector
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    // Remove duplicates (v1)
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::unique_copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(result));

    // Print results
    std::cout << "Result v1: ";
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Remove duplicates (v2)
    std::vector<int> result2;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0 && vec[i] == vec[i - 1])
            continue;
        result2.push_back(vec[i]);
    }

    // Print results (v2)
    std::cout << "Result v2: ";
    std::copy(result2.begin(), result2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think there is still something missing, because when I added another integer it didnt work correctly. I mean I added an integer 8 and the output was just 10 6.    8 was not even there

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Just in case, I added another vec.push_back(8); and both results (v1 and v2) were correct: 6 8 10. Please use the entire code I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a list for this. Use a set:

```
 #include <set>
 ...
 set<int> vec;
```

This will ensure you will have no duplicates by not adding an element if it already exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am only allowed to use loops

Comment: @user2878007: so what? You can loop through any container.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is here:

```
for(int j=vec.size()-1; j>=0; j--)
{
    if(vec[j] == vec[i-1])
        vec.erase(vec.begin() + j);
}
```

there's going to be a time when `j==i-1` and that's going to kill your algorithms and there will be a time when `i-1 < 0` so you will get an out of boundary exception.

What you can do is to change your for loop conditions:

```
for (int i = vec.size() - 1; i>0; i--){
    for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

this way, your the two variables your comparing will never be the same and your indices will always be at least 0.

Comment: by the way there is serious problem with `vec[i-1]` when i == 0

Comment: The codes you wrote are incomplete and its impossible to work

Comment: @user2878007 do you want me to rewrite the whole main method for you?

Comment: Of course not, but help me to write the part inside your loop.

Comment: you mean the `//do stuff` part?

Comment: yeah. I am afraid I can't make it

Comment: I will edit the answer and change it a bit. I'm not a fan of modifying the datastructure we are looping through within the loop.

Comment: o okay. Then I'll leave as is.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to save initial order of numbers you can make a function that will remove duplicates using helper `set<int>` structure:

```
void removeDuplicates( vector<int>& v )
{
    set<int> s;
    vector<int> res;
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
        int x = v[i];
        if( s.find(x) == s.end() ) {
            s.insert(x);
            res.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    swap(v, res);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed to `std::set`. This is certainly simple and easy--but it can be fairly slow (quite a bit slower than `std::vector`, largely because (like a linked list) it consists of individually allocated nodes, linked together via pointers to form a balanced tree<sup>1</sup>.

You can (often) improve on that by using an `std::unordered_set` instead of a `std::set`. This uses a hash table<sup>2</sup> instead of a tree to store the data, so it normally uses contiguous storage, and gives O(1) expected access time instead of the O(log N) expected for a tree.

An alternative that's often faster is to collect the data in the vector, then sort the data and use `std::unique` to eliminate duplicates. This tends to be best when you have two distinct phases of operation: first you collect all the data, *then* you need duplicates removed. If you frequently alternate between adding/deleting data, and needing a duplicate free set, then something like `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` that maintain the set without duplicates at all times may be more useful.

All of these also affect the *order* of the items. An `std::set` always maintains the items sorted in a defined order. With `std::unique` you need to explicit sort the data. With `std::unordered_set` you get the items sorted in an arbitrary order that's neither their original order *nor* is it sorted.

If you need to maintain the original order, but without duplicates, you normally end up needing to store the data twice. For example when you need to add a new item, you attempt to insert it into an `std::unordered_set`, then if and only if that succeeds, add it to the vector as well.

---

1. Technically, implementation as a tree isn't strictly required, but it's about the only possibility of which I'm aware that can meet the requirements, and all the implementations of which I'm aware are based on trees.
2. Again, other implementations might be theoretically possible, but all of which I'm aware use hashing--but in this case, enough of the implementation is exposed that avoiding a hash table would probably be even more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The body of a range for must not change the size of the sequence over which it is iterating..

you can remove duplicates before push_back

```
void push(std::vector<int> & arr, int n)
{

    for(int i = 0; i != arr.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(arr[i] == n) 
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    arr.push_back(n);
}

... ... 

push(vec, a);

push(vec, b);

push(vec, c);
...
```